# Redux - how to react on change once

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

I am using redux to react on changes in my applications state and render the ui according to my state. Now certain components need a one time method call.

**Following example:**

I have a grid. Selecting an item in a grid changes the state of my app and I set the `selected` attribute to this item.

Adding an item, sets the `selected` attribute of my state to the added item. But then the grid needs a call to `grid.clearCache()` to actually render the added item.

The state in both cases looks actually the same and I don't want to call the `clearCache` function if not needed. The items are not part of the state and lazily loaded by the component itself.

Adding a `clearcache` attribute to the state and setting it back afterwards feels not right.

How do I achieve the desired behavior? How to design the state correctly in this case?

Comment: Redux+Immutable,I think there is no need to care when to call render method,Action only care about the change of state.Then Redux will lead to UI rerender.

Answer (score 1):

What about to store an additional flag like firstUpdate: true ?

Comment: Yes, that was my idea. But on the next state change, the flag is still true. Then I have to call an action to set the state back to false. Feels a bit awkward to call 2 actions to react on one change. Is this the right redux way?

Comment: If you need two (consecutive) change to your app state is fine to call two actions, also for debugging and logging.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your problem enough. If you add new item, the props will change, so the Grid should update automatically (thanks for React magic). There's no need to one more call `grid.clearCache()`.

Here's my simple design reducer for your problem.

```
const preState = {
  items: {
    1: {
      id: 1,
      itemName: '1'
    },
    2: {
      id: 2,
      itemName: '2'
    }
  },
  order: [1, 2],
  selectedItem: 1
}

export default (state = preState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SELECT_ITEM':
      return {
        ...state,
        selectedItem: action.itemId
      }
    case 'ADD_NEW_ITEM':
      return {
        ...state,
        items: {
          ...state.items,
          [action.item.id]: action.item
        },
        order: [...state.order, action.item.id],
        selectedItem: action.item.id
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And your `Grid Component` should read `items` and `selectedItem` (`order` if you need to sort the items) from redux store.

Comment: The items are lazily loaded (e.g. while scrolling) and showing possible thousands of elements. So I don't want to hold the items as part of the state.

Comment: But not all the elements are shown in the view, right? You should just keep a small amount of items in the store while continue append new items / slice old items (maybe manage about 100~500 latest items at a time).

For the other hands, it's same if you keep data in React state / Redux store. It's just about how you design your Application State. If you don't keep the data in the state, where else do you keep them?

Comment: The grid is a web component I have not written myself, but it works as you described. I provide it a dataprovider func. This dataprovider retrieves its data from indexeddb. I store in the state only the filter, sortorder and scroll position but not the data itself. If data is added to the indexeddb, the grid has to retrieve all its data again, thats why I have to call clearcache. In other applications I would probably work with events.

Comment: I see... I think you can use `forceUpdate()` to force your Component re-render without any state change.